# Adding data to created sqlite database in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created two classes in models.py in my application.

models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class User(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name

 class NewUser(models.Model):
 categorie = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
 area = models.CharField(max_length=264)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

[image]

as shown in my image my (User and New users)tables are created.
data is getting added to my (User) table.
But when I try to add data to my (New users) table 
I get this error
[image]

Comment: have you migrated after creating second model

Comment: yes I have migrated

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I kindly suggest you use django.contrib.auth for all user management stuff...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers,Sorry, I have deleted the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any custom fields in your User model, you dont need to create a seperate User class, only you have to import the built in User class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUser(models.Model):
   categorie = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   area = models.CharField(max_length=264)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.categorie.user.username
```

You can still get username, first_name, last_name, email etc from the default user class. Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: I think the name (NewUser)  is misleading. I dont want to create a new user. I just want to create another table and add data to it. The name can be anything other than new user

Comment: naming you can change as you wish, it should be relevant to the project, so that in future you or any other developers can trace it.

Comment: I have a "class User" in my models.py just like yours. When I tried to make migrations and migrate, there are no tables created. When I renamed it to "class Person" it created a bunch of tables along with the table "projectApp_person"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't migrated properly. Try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

The models show up in the admin because they are present in the apps `models.py`. This is not related to the database!